# How to use the same num_workers for train and val dataloaders in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, out-of-memory

I am currently using PyTorch to train the transformer models.

With 100GB of RAM, I am able to train the model with `num_workers=4` i.e. it uses 4 CPUs in parallel to load 4 datasets. If I allocate `num_workers=1` to the validation `dataloader`, it works fine. However, `num_workers=2` to the validation `dataloader` results in an OOM error. This implies that each worker takes up to 20GB of RAM. I can't have more than 100GB of RAM at the moment.

Allocating 1 `num_worker` for the validation dataloader is extremely slow such that it takes 4 hours to complete one round of validation. Is there a way to make use of `num_workers` assigned to the training dataloaders for validation as well?

Comment: If they both use the same preprocessing. How about using only one Dataloader for both train and val and do the shuffle in Dataset's `__getitem__`?

Comment: That's a good suggestion! I haven't tried that, but I will have to give it a try to see if that works. Any idea if something can be done without changing anything in the code? Sort of like a parameter in PyTorch that allows it to happen automatically?

Comment: No idea, I've never run into this problem. Just to be sure it's the system ram that ran out not the GPU right?

Comment: Ahh yeah! It's the system RAM.

Comment: It turns out that dataloaders free up `num_workers` when they finish iterating. They start using RAM once they resetart their iterations. So I ended up validating at the end of training dataloaders `__iter__`.